# Matlab error: "PCA requires 2 inputs"

Tags: matlab

I've been using PCA for quite a while on 2D-arrays and it has worked perfectly.

All of a sudden PCA doesn't work on a single input (2D-array), and requires two inputs. In the MathWorks documentation it lists one input paramater as an option.

I've tried the "dummy" example here: http://se.mathworks.com/help/stats/pca.html and I get the same error.

"pca requires 2 inputs"

Any ideas on why?

Comment: Did you accidentally define a function yourself named `pca.m`? Check by typing `which('pca')`

Comment: What was printed when you typed `which('pca')`?

Comment: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015b\toolbox\pls_toolbox_811\pca.p

If I remove the pca.p-file, it doesn't work at all.

Comment: Yup ok so you have a third party toolbox that you downloaded that created a function called `pca` which broke yours (shame on them!). I would uninstall the toolbox, or if you want, you can always use `builtin('pca', data)` to call the builtin one

Comment: Thanks! After uninstalling the third party toolbox, Matlab was not able to find PCA at all. Now I have reinstalled Matlab, and it works great!

Comment: Next time, rather than reinstalling, you should be able to call either `rehash toolboxreset` or restart MATLAB.

Answer (score 0):

In short, there are two pca functions in the path, and the built in help shows info for the wrong one.

I got the same error.  I found that when I right click on the pca command it takes me to the Matlab help for the pca function.  But, when I right click and 'open selection' it takes me to a different implementation of the function.  The command 'pca' in my matlab install was overwritten by the 'pca' command from the pls toolbox.

If you are using pls toolbox the second input is the number of components to be computed.